# Is it possible to change the size and look of blocks/symbols in Quartus Schematic Editor

Tags: schematics, quartus

I want to change shapes of and resize blocks/symbols to make the schematic tidier. For example, I want to make my multiplexers the shape of a trapezoid (like commonly drawn on paper) and make them smaller so they will be not as big as, for example, a CPU I have designed.

This is a problem because sometimes a multiplexer has to be added as an input to every pin of another block, then the whole design looks like a great big mess.

Is there a way to do those in Quartus Prime Lite.

Comment: try sending an email to Altera

Comment: look through the program files .... look for png files, xml files, any files that contain xml info  .... use a text editor like notepad++ to search the directory tree for words like XOR  and NAND and MUX

Comment: To see how they added shapes to the basic logic gates, you mean. I will try.

Comment: yes, the shape may be a picture as a PNG file (lossless format, no weird artifacts like with jpeg) ..... it may be defined in a text file (XML, some other extension) ..... maybe even an SVG file ............. or it may be built into the program and therefore not findable

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so.

The schematic editor is essentially a toy. My understanding is that it is primarily included for feature parity with other software, and for introductory use in educational environments. It is not intended to be used for complex designs -- you are expected to use HDL in a production environment.